# Cannot disable/override context menu Safari fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, html, video, safari

When using Safari in fullscreen mode, cannot disable or override context menu (right click / ctrl + click on video).

Normally, one can disable or override using a oncontextmenu handler:

```
videoEl.oncontextmenu = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault(); // or return false;
}
```

The above works for all browsers including Safari when not in fullscreen mode.  However the code does not fire when video is in Safari fullscreen mode.  To reproduce, simply go fullscreen and do ctrl + click.  The default context menu will show.

I also though about catching click/keyboard events but those don't fire in fullscreen mode either.

However other players such as Youtube's are able to disable and override the context menu when in Safari fullscreen mode.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using both `e.preventDefault()` *and* `return false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering here because the existing replies (thank you) didn't resolve the issue.

The "controls" attribute must be removed from player.  Unfortunately this also requires re-implementing all the player controls.

Using this approach you can prevent right click menu in Safari fullscreen mode and provide your own custom menu if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
videoEl.oncontextmenu =
    function () {
        return false;
    };
```

This may work too:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display:none !important;
}
```

Also, just a friendly reminder that it's not really recommended to disable the context menu, as it doesn't protect your source code at all and it can lead to an annoying user experience.

Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: *it doesn't protect your source code at all* . . . If a simple change can be used to deter the majority of non-technical users from getting illegitimate access to your content, sometimes it is worth it.